4 ⊂ A vs {4} ⊂ A, Is there a difference?
The question is
"Compare the set A = {2,3,5,7}, B = {1,2,3,4} and indicate if the following statements are true or false."
Q.3 is "4 ⊂ A"
Q.4 is "{4} ⊂ A"
I'm not sure if there is a difference or if brackets change anything.
Is 4 ⊂ A false because you need curly brackets for it to be considered a set?

So, what’s your opinion, true or false? What have you learned about sets.

$4$ is not a set, ${4}$ is a set.

What do curly brackets do? I think that both are false because 4 is not an element in A but because both questions are there. I think my hypothesis is wrong; one must be false and the other true.

@Nini Actually all two of the statements are wrong.

Agreed. The curly brackets (also known as accolades, braces or set brackets) describe a set whereas their absence implies an element in a set. An element belongs (or does not) in a set whereas one set can (or not) be a subset of another. In this case, both statements are false.

At the elementary level with finite discrete sets, individual elements would be listed in curly brackets. Philosophically one could wonder "what is $4$?" maybe $4$ is a set, and maybe $4={2,3}$
